# allow only unique entries in array windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to write a windows Batch file to obtain below OUTPUT for given INPUT

INPUT:

```
//Dev-420/PAVAN/src/main/java/test/abcd/mnop/HealthCheck.java - edit change 1111111
 //Dev-420/PAVAN/src/main/java/test/abcd/mnop/HealthStatus.java - edit change 1111111
 //Dev-420/PAVAN/src/main/java/test/xyz/Relations.java - edit change 1111112
```

OUTPUT:

array CHANGELIST should hold only unique values

```
[1111111, 1111112]
```

now its giving as `[1111111,1111111,1111112]`

Below is the script I am using.
I dint found a way to do this.

```
@echo off
set "File2Read=files_list.tmp"
set "FILENAME="
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /a count=0
set "BINARY_FILENAME="
set "replaceBinaryPath=target/classes/"
set "basePath=//ATT/Dev-420/PAVAN/src/main/java/"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%File2Read%"') do (
    set "line=%%a"
    for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5 delims= " %%a in ("!line!") do (
      set FILENAME=%%a
      set CHANGELIST=%%e
    )

    set "BINARY_FILENAME=!FILENAME:%basePath%=%replaceBinaryPath%!"
    if not !FILENAME!==!BINARY_FILENAME! (
        set /a count+=1
        set "CHANGELISTS[!count!]=!CHANGELIST!"
    )
)
endLocal
```

Please help me to some way to be able to insert only unique values in `CHANGELISTS` array.

Will really appreciate your help here!

Comment: I ran your script using your data and I get no output at all. Are you sure this is an [MCVE]?

Comment: Do you need to preserve order?

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to test/debug scripts when you avoid multi-line code blocks. I removed the redundant loop and striped off the extraneous bits.

```
@setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
@rem echo off
@set "_fileToRead=files_list.tmp"
@for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4,5" %%I in (%_fileToRead%) do @call :DoIt "%%I" %%M

@exit /b 0

:Append
@if "" equ "%_changeList%" (@set _changeList=%1) else (@set _changeList=%_changeList% %1)
@exit /b 0

:DoIt
@call :SetFound %2
@if %_found% equ false @call :Append %2
@rem This is where you do something with the path/file in %1
@echo %~1 %2
@echo %_changeList%
@exit /b 0

:SetFound
@set _found=false
@for /f "tokens=1" %%a in ("%_changeList%") do @if %%a equ %1 @set _found=true
@exit /b 0
```

Produces this output with your test data:

```
//Dev-420/PAVAN/src/main/java/test/abcd/mnop/HealthCheck.java 1111111
1111111
//Dev-420/PAVAN/src/main/java/test/abcd/mnop/HealthStatus.java 1111111
1111111
//Dev-420/PAVAN/src/main/java/test/xyz/Relations.java 1111112
1111111 1111112
```

Should be easy enough for you to build off that.